# Error listview items

Tags: android, listview, arraylist, adapter

Hi im trying to do my first app in android.I want to make listviews with Contextmenu but when i try to compile i have errors.This is my code:

error in instancias();

error  in : lista.setAdapter(a);

error in paiseslista();

here is the log:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
                                                                         at sergio.dialogosprueba.mainactivity.paisesLista(mainactivity.java:66)
                                                                         at sergio.dialogosprueba.mainactivity.instancias(mainactivity.java:58)
                                                                         at sergio.dialogosprueba.mainactivity.onCreate(mainactivity.java:30)
```

The activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button vuelos,fecha;
    ListView lista;
    ArrayList<String> array;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        instancias();

        vuelos.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(mainactivity.this, secondactivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }

        });

        fecha.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(mainactivity.this, secondactivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }

        });

    }

    private void instancias() {
            vuelos = (Button) findViewById(R.id.vuelos);
            fecha = (Button) findViewById(R.id.fecha);
            lista =(ListView) findViewById(R.id.lista);
            array = new ArrayList<String>();
            array.add("Roma");
            array.add("Madrid");
            array.add("Paris");
            paisesLista();
            registerForContextMenu(lista);



        }

    private void paisesLista() {
        ArrayAdapter a = new ArrayAdapter(mainactivity.this,android.R.layout.list_content,array);
        lista.setAdapter(a);



    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: and what is the exact error message?

Comment: Fatal exception main

Comment: very helpful, thanks

Comment: sorry im new here.Edited

Answer (score 1):

lista is null in paisesLista. Try to debug, and see what's the value of lista after the line:

```
lista =(ListView) findViewById(R.id.lista);
```

Probably there's a problem with your layout. Check that it has the id "lista"

According to your comments, you want to use second_layout.xml, so you'll need to change the line from:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

to:

```
setContentView(R.layout. second_layout);
```

Comment: its added in second_layout.xml

Comment: There are only 2 problems with that: 1. second_layout is not used in this Activity, 2. I still can't read your mind and see the xml... Try: setContentView(R.layout.second_layout);

Comment: can you share the secret second_layout.xml with us?